How can I define a recursive type alias in TypeScript to represent deeply nested structures?
Context:
I'm developing a TypeScript application that processes hierarchical data structures, such as nested arrays or tree-like objects. To ensure type safety and code clarity, I aim to define a recursive type alias that accurately represents these deeply nested structures. However, I'm encountering challenges in implementing this recursive type definition effectively.
const nestedNumbers = [1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]];

I attempted to define a recursive type alias as follows:
type NestedArray = number | NestedArray[];

However, this results in a TypeScript error
Type alias 'NestedArray' circularly references itself.

Expected vs. Actual Results:
Expected: I anticipated that the NestedArray type alias would allow for an array containing numbers or other NestedArray instances, effectively capturing the recursive nature of the data structure.
Actual: TypeScript throws a circular reference error, indicating that my recursive type alias definition is incorrect.
I explored TypeScript's documentation and community forums to understand recursive type aliases. I found that TypeScript supports recursive types, but they must be structured correctly to avoid circular reference errors. For instance, defining a recursive type for a JSON-like structure can be done as:
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };

This approach is discussed in the TypeScript 3.7 release notes, which introduced support for recursive type aliases.
Despite this, applying a similar pattern to my NestedArray type results in errors, and I haven't found a clear explanation or solution in the resources I've consulted.

I cannot reproduce

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Like @Bergi I don't see the problem you're describing in my IDE; the code works just fine, as you expect it to. Please [edit] to provide enough debugging details to reproduce the problem, or the question risks being closed as needing such information. Good luck!
